# User privileges issue on network share when accessed using WebDav

Tags: windows, iis, webdav

I have a network share setup on Windows 2008 R2 Server. The directory structure is like:

Dir1- SubDir1 and SubDir2

There are two Users - User1 and User2.

User1 has full access to all the directories in NTFS permissions but User2 has no access to SubDir2.

When I access the WebDav site using User2 the first I get the proper structure i.e. the SubDir2 is not returned.

Then I access the site using User1 and I get the proper structure again i.e. the SubDir2 is also shown.

After this if I access the site again using User2 the SubDir2 is also returned in the structure.

I enabled Audit Logging on the shared directory and it shows that the request is coming from the correct user, but stil cannot figure out why the SubDir2 shows up for the User2 after the site has been accessed bu User1.

Comment: That sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: I am not sure because the audit logs on the machine where the shared directory is shows the correct user trying to access the share. I also thought initially it was a caching issue but could not find any credentials caching for webdav in IIS

Comment: I tested using the browser, a webdav client and c# code and it was the same result for all of them. In all the cases the username and password given was for the two users and the audit log on the shared directory showed the correct user logging in from each one of these users.